# Using Canvas to draw multiple polygons but can not get color to be different for polygons

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, polygon

I an issue with the implementation of drawing multiple polygons on a canvas.

I draw the two polygons,
when I move the mouse into the 2nd polygon it turns red and so does the first polygon (the first polygon should be blue). When I move the mouse into the 1st polygon it  turns red and so does the 2nd polygon (the 2nd polygon should be blue).

I found the issue with research of each canvas call;  adding a ctx.beginPath() fixed the issue. See below:

```
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width=600 height=600 ></canvas>




        <script>
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    myimage = new Image();
    myimage.src = 'https://i.postimg.cc/SNjPPZGJ/farms-map.png';
    myimage.onload = draw


    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const polypoints1 = [{x: 200, y: 29}, {x: 500, y: 19}, {x: 465, y: 146}, {x: 130, y: 150}];
    const polypoints2 = [{x: 200, y: 229}, {x: 500, y: 219}, {x: 465, y: 346}, {x: 130, y: 350}];

    var polyColor = [];
    var dragPoint = null;
   
    draw();
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
              polyColor[0]="blue";
              polyColor[1]="blue";
      if (inside({x:evt.clientX - rect.left, y:(evt.clientY + window.scrollY) - rect.top}, polypoints1)){
              polyColor[0]="red";
              polyColor[1]="blue";}
      if (inside({x:evt.clientX - rect.left, y:(evt.clientY + window.scrollY) - rect.top}, polypoints2)){
             polyColor[0]="blue";
             polyColor[1]="red";}
    
      draw()
    }, false);

    function inside(p, vs) {
        var inside = false;
        for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
            var xi = vs[i].x, yi = vs[i].y;
            var xj = vs[j].x, yj = vs[j].y;
            var intersect = ((yi > p.y) != (yj > p.y)) && (p.x < (xj - xi) * (p.y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
            if (intersect) inside = !inside;
        }
        return inside;
    };


    function draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      if (myimage) {
              ctx.drawImage(myimage, 1, 1)  
      }
      drawLines();
      polypoints1.forEach(p => drawPoint(p));
      polypoints2.forEach(p => drawPoint(p));
    }


    function drawPoint(p) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.globalAlpha = 1
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();
    }

    function drawLines() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      polypoints1.forEach(p => ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y));
      ctx.lineTo(polypoints1[0].x, polypoints1[0].y);

     
       ctx.stroke();
      if (!dragPoint) {
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2
        ctx.fillStyle = polyColor[0];
        ctx.fill();
      }
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      polypoints2.forEach(p => ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y));
      ctx.lineTo(polypoints2[0].x, polypoints2[0].y);
      ctx.stroke();
      if (!dragPoint) {
       ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2
        ctx.fillStyle = polyColor[1];
        ctx.fill();
      }
    }

    function findDragPoint(x, y) {
      for (i = 0; i < polypoints1.length; i++) {
        if (hitTest(polypoints1[i], x, y)) return polypoints1[i];
        if (hitTest(polypoints2[i], x, y)) return polypoints2[i];
      };
      return null;
    }

    function onMouseDown(event) {
      dragPoint = findDragPoint(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop + window.scrollY);
      if (dragPoint) {
        dragPoint.x = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        dragPoint.y = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop + window.scrollY;
        draw();
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
      }
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
      dragPoint.x = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      dragPoint.y = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop+ window.scrollY;
      draw();
    }

    function onMouseUp() {
      dragPoint = null;
      draw();
      canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
      canvas.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);  
    }

    function hitTest(p, x, y) {
      var dx = p.x - x, dy = p.y - y;
      return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= 10;
    }
       </script>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to put your code here. You (perhaps unwittingly) skirted that rule by formatting your list as code.

Comment: Remember to follow the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): one question for one problem, and show the code that is relevant to that single problem in your post (ideally as runnable snippet), even if you also have a link to a third party website with that code. Your post should still make sense if that third party site drops off the internet.

Comment: And remember to reduce your code to a [mcve]: there is tons of stuff in the code right now that's simply not related to the problem. That might sound like pedantry, but the whole point of getting you to form an MCVE is because it almost always leads to you discovering what's wrong all on your own, and in the rare few cases it doesn't, you have _the perfect code_ for putting in any forum post.

Comment: OK.   Thanks for the feed back.  Let me create the problem with multiple polygon colors.   I need about 2 hours.

Comment: I have updated the posting based on the feed back I received from isherwood  and Mike Kamermans .  Let me know if there is still  more for me to do to get the issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you have to use ctx.beginPath()  before you start to set up the second polygon. This seems to have addressed the issue.

Comment: While it's good that you managed to solve your problem, it would be more helpful to the community if you also showed the actual code change you made in your answer. And it would also be helpful if you can add an explanation of why that solved your issue.

Comment: Done. See updated post

Comment: OK, but now you have inadvertently made the situation far worse, because you have posted the solution within the question, removed the original code from your question, posted your solution within the question, and left your answer which needed clarification unchanged.

Comment: Please do the following: [1] Undo the changes you had made to _your question_ by posting the solution within it. [2] Update _this answer_ with the code changes you made to fix the problem, and an explanation of why the change fixed the problem. (And thanks for taking the time to post a solution at all. That helps the community.)

Comment: skomisa, I am new to this so hopefully you understand my missteps.   Is there some way to undo the changes I made to the posting?  I am unable to find how to do that and I am not that eager to recreate it from scratch.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand, and no harm done. I just wanted you to be aware of how things work here. There is a `Rollback` feature allowing the reversion of a post to an earlier edited version, although I have never used it. In this case you can still edit your answer to show the complete function you changed to add `ctx.beginPath()`, and add a brief explanation of why it fixes the issue.

Comment: If you want to regress your question, you can do that by clicking the `Flag` button which is just below your question. On the screen that opens there is an option titled _"in need of moderator intervention"_. Select that option, and request that your question be rollbacked to its earlier state, so that it contains the earlier code with the issue. But no biggie - it's just one question, and it's more important that you understand how things work here.